# What exactly are Large Hydraulic Cylinders used for?

Tags: actuator

There are hydraulic cylinders with the size of a train wagon, or a smaller building, like this one:

[image]

But what are they used for? Could you please give a few examples in the world: perhaps metal processing factories, mining machines (guess)? Maybe provide a link to a few pictures on their applications, or cases where they are assembled into something larger?

Thanks!

Comment: Speaking of "the size of a train wagon", the Soviet N1 "grasshopper" TE had some impressive [rams](https://www.flickr.com/photos/martintrolle/4670762891).

Answer (score 1):

Have been used on offshore oil rigs to get the platform level compared to the sea bed.

Comment: AKA motion compensators , to prevent the drill bit from bouncing in the hole.